# What other proof methods are there?

Tags: proof-of-work, proof-of-stake

I am familiar with the proof of work method and a little with the proof of stake method. Is there any more methods that are out there and how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few others on top of my head, in addition to variations of PoS (DPoS, LPoS, etc)

- [Proof of Importance (PoI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEM_(cryptocurrency)#Proof-of-importance): kinda like PoS, but stake here is the total transaction amount (greater than some vested amount of coin)
- [Proof of Authority (PoA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-authority): transactions are validated by selected validators
- [Proof of Burn (PoB)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_burn): please refer to this SE question: [How does Proof of Burn work?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50525/how-does-proof-of-burn-work)